# Why does MySQL set Transaction level by session

Tags: mysql, serialization

Why MySQL can have multiple sessions set with different transaction levels to operate on the same table without conflicts?

If transaction A is Repeatable reading and transaction B is Serialization, what happens to transaction A when transaction B runs?

Comment: When two or more transactions need to read or write the same rows then one transaction has to wait for the other to complete first.

Comment: Isolation level primarily affects the transaction it is set on, not the other transactions. The way transactions affect each other are through locks. Since the available locks types are the same across all isolation levels, transactions running in different isolation levels can interact with each other just fine.

Comment: As you said, I can understand other transaction levels, but what about the Serialization? Isn't its function to only allow one transaction to run at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SERIALIZABLE` transactions do not block other transactions from reading, regardless of the other transaction's isolation level.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html:

> - `SERIALIZABLE`
>
>   This level is like `REPEATABLE READ`, but InnoDB implicitly converts all plain `SELECT` statements to `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` if `autocommit` is disabled.

That's all it does.

Multiple sessions can still read the same data concurrently, and they don't conflict. Even multiple `SERIALIZABLE` transactions can all read the same data, because multiple sessions can hold shared locks.

Where they conflict is with exclusive locks. So they block, and are blocked by, any transaction that tries to get an exclusive lock on those rows. E.g. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, or any other DML like `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` or DDL like `ALTER/DROP/TRUNCATE`.

This means changes to the table are serialized, but reads are not.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much